# What should we do to get soajs to run on nodejs>0.12

Tags: javascript, node.js, soajs

For now,

We had to downgrade our NodeJS platform to use version 0.12 
to get our SOAjs dashboard working.

What is needed in our SOAjs implementation to use the newest NodeJS
versions ?

Thx

Comment: Asking how to resolve the error thrown by soajs on the recent node.js version may be a better than trying to etablish a list of every nook and cranny, no? Especially since soajs doesn t look dead (commit some days ago), so the problem should not be in the node.js version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the nodejs constraint on version 0.12 was happening on the MacOS dashboard deployment only.

It is not appearing on the Linux installations we have seen so far.

So no changes on our SOAjs integration code is needed.